# save changes multiple txt

Tags: php, html, forms, button, save

I've got some issues with my PHP code. I want to load two `.txt` to edit with the browser (chrome, ie, any) and saves changes through just one button. Until now, I can do it with multiple buttons, but thats risky cos if you forget to save one change you lose it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$fn = "../txt/example.txt";

if (isset($_POST['agenda1a']))
{
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['agenda1a']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error");
}
?>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor_titulo">Agenda 1</div>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
      <textarea name="agenda1a" cols="55" rows="25" class="editor_texto"><?php readfile($fn); ?>
</textarea>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn_entrar" id="btn_guardar" value="  Guardar este menú  ">
    </form>
  </div>

  <?php
$fn = "../txt/example2.txt";

if (isset($_POST['agenda1b']))
{
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['agenda1b']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error");
}
?>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor_titulo">Agenda 2</div>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
      <textarea name="agenda1b" cols="55" rows="25" class="editor_texto"><?php readfile($fn); ?>
</textarea>
      <input type="submit" class="btn_entrar" id="btn_guardar" value="  Guardar este menú  ">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to place the `<textarea>` elements under the same `<form>`. This can be done with the code you've presented, but you'll likely have to make some styling changes, as one of the `.editor` elements is removed.

```
<?php
$fn1 = "../txt/example.txt";

if (isset($_POST['agenda1a']))
{
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['agenda1a']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error");
}

$fn2 = "../txt/example2.txt";

if (isset($_POST['agenda1b']))
{
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['agenda1b']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error");
}
?>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor_titulo">Agenda 1</div>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
      <textarea name="agenda1a" cols="55" rows="25" class="editor_texto"><?php readfile($fn1); ?>
</textarea>

    <div class="editor_titulo">Agenda 2</div>
      <textarea name="agenda1b" cols="55" rows="25" class="editor_texto"><?php readfile($fn2); ?>
</textarea>
      <input type="submit" class="btn_entrar" id="btn_guardar" value="  Guardar este menú  ">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've try it and it works fine to me! brf... i've been stucked and it was logical! of course they have to be in the same form! thanks again!

Comment: (yei, finally I see that I had to change fn to fn1 and fn2, but rest is great!!!! :D)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, put all of your fields (`<textarea>` elements) into a single `<form>` tag, and have a single save button.

Once you've done that, you can combine your code for saving both files. Note that you'll only get the posted values from one `<form>` at a time, that's why the code needs to be merged.

Something like this should suffice:

```
<?php
$file_one = "../txt/example.txt";
$file_two = "../txt/example2.txt";

$file_one_content = file_get_contents($file_one);
$file_two_content = file_get_contents($file_two);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Save the files
    $file_one_content = stripslashes($_POST['agenda1a']);
    file_put_contents($file_one, $file_one_content);
    $file_two_content = stripslashes($_POST['agenda1b']);
    file_put_contents($file_one, $file_two_content);
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor_titulo">Agenda 1</div>
      <textarea name="agenda1a" cols="55" rows="25" class="editor_texto"><?php echo $file_one_content ?></textarea>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn_entrar" id="btn_guardar" value="  Guardar este menú  ">
  </div>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor_titulo">Agenda 2</div>
      <textarea name="agenda1b" cols="55" rows="25" class="editor_texto"><?php echo $file_two_content ?></textarea>
      <input type="submit" class="btn_entrar" id="btn_guardar" value="  Guardar este menú  ">
  </div>
</form>
```

*(Note: The code above uses `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents` so you can open/save in 1 line of code, and only checks for `$_POST['submit']` for simplicity)*

Comment: Uou! thanks for your quick answer!! i've just try to make changes that you sugest, but explorer shows this: Fatal error: Call to undefined function: file_put_contents() in /homez.95/iloftyou/www/syntagma/editor/editor.php on line 40

Comment: @user1249723 `file_put_contents` is a method in PHP5, so that you don't have to use `fopen` etc. Are you on PHP4? I'd really suggest you upgrade immediately.

Comment: yeah you're right! I forget to change that!! argh it's an oooooold domain that I don't use it anymore! thanks for the help!